Deploy non public staging application with Node.js/express
We are developing a Node.js / Express web application. We would like to deploy a confidential preprod/staging version of the app before deploying the new public version.
My team makes some tests on the staging version to check everything is OK before pushing the version to production.
We don't want this version to be publicly available. We need an authentication system to reach the staging version. I can't figure out how to create this staging version with  authentication without modifying the source code that will no longer be the same in staging and in production.
Is there any tools or tricks to do that properly?

The question is too unspecific. What is the problem with having auth code in production version that won't be used? Even if there's a problem, you could provide any kind of auth through a webserver, e.g. nginx, apart from app server.

That's unspecific because I don't know how to do ! We would like to have exactly the same code in staging and production. I've never heard that web servers could provide high level authentification. I expected feedback from experimented devops when asking this question.

You can have auth middleware in app server that's conditionally enabled depending on the env. Or you can restrict access on web server level, e.g. with basic auth or magic cookie. Or you can just rely on security through obscurity if accessing a preprod server provides no real security risk. It's totally up to you, there's no consensus. I'd go with any of these options depending on the case
